# Zoom Controls in google maps URL

Tags: google-maps, url

I am building Google Map URL that will point few locations in the map

I want to add Zoom control to the map so users can zoom in and out

all the examples i saw were for java script and coding maps

is there any parameter i can add to the url to get the zooming control

I tried

```
&callback=initMap

&gestureHandling=cooperative
```

but non worked

any one know what i have to add to get scrolling and zooming controls?

my current URL looks like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&gestureHandling=cooperative&size=1200x800&maptype=roadmap&key=AIza***********************&markers=label:1%7C-33.87277000,151.21408000&markers=label:2%7C-33.87257000,151.21520000
```

Comment: you are requesting a static image - for zoom control you will need to embed a map

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start is a good starting point to do the embedded map with zoom controls